# Nested cursors, multiple result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I'm using a SQL Server stored procedure to generate an Excel report. Basically each "entry" in the report has three parts: Object, Observation, and Points. The observations have a reference to the primary key of an object, and the points have a reference to an observation. That is the relationship between the parts. (Sorry if my terminology is off, I am used to writing in C# or Java but still learning SQL.)

I want the output to be like this:

```
-Object

  -All Observations linked to that Object

    - Under each observation there should be all the points linked to that observation
```

And repeat for each object. I have this working using a cursor for generating all observations with each object, but I can't get the points to come up under each observation.

I have read all over the Internet that cursors are Bad, and I assume this means nested cursors are Very Bad. But this is what I have so far. If you know of a better way to do this, please tell me. I am open to totally refactoring this if necessary.

```
  DECLARE @Object_Cursor cursor
  DECLARE @Observation_Cursor cursor
  DECLARE @i int
  DECLARE @j int
  DECLARE @row int = 1
  SET @Object_Cursor = CURSOR FOR (SELECT PK_ObjectId FROM Objects)
  OPEN @Object_Cursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM @Object_Cursor INTO @i
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
    Select 
        PK_ObjectID,
        Name,
        Timestamp
    From Objects where PK_ObjectID = @i


  SET @Observation_Cursor = CURSOR FOR (SELECT @PK_ObservationID FROM Observations)
  OPEN @Observation_Cursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM @Observation_Cursor INTO @j
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
    Select
        Timestamp,
        Note,
        User
        from Observations
        where FK_ObjectId = @i
        order by FK_ObjectID

    Select Lat, Lng 
    From Pts
    Where FK_ObservationID = @j
    Fetch Next From @Observation_Cursor into @j
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM @Object_Cursor into @i
    END

    Close @Observation_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE @Observation_Cursor
    CLOSE @Object_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE @Object_Cursor
```

I feel like the order I'm executing these loops is off somehow, but I haven't been able to get it. Current output is:

```
 -Object    
   -Observations for that object
    -empty points result set
```

These results are repeated several times for the same object before it goes to the next one, and the points are always empty.

Any help or pointers in another direction is much appreciated.

Comment: c# thinking doesn't work well in SQL. Rethink, don't use loops.  Any reason this isn't done as three table join in one sedlect statement?

Comment: Ugh!! Nested cursors. This is going to be as slow as molasses outside in Alaska during the winter.

Comment: @Twelfth Well, I need the results to be sort of separate cause there are multiple observations for each object, and multiple points for each observation. I wasn't sure how to combine that into one select statement and maintain the structure I need.

Comment: YOu'll end up getting the multiple rows...1 line from objects * multiple lines per observation * multiple rows per pts.

Comment: @SeanLange - heh, my preference is to describe it as trying to travel a few miles while stopping every 2 feet to rebuild your car from the ground up ;)

Comment: @Twelfth that is also a good analogy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# loop logic isn't how you want to think for SQL...1 statement is always preferable.

I think this is close to what you want...i'm guessing a bit at your keys in the join.

```
Select 
    (pick your fields here)
From Objects
left join Observations on objects.PK_ObjectID  = Observations.FK_ObjectID
left join Pts on Pts.FK_ObservationID  = observations.pk_observation_ID
```

Comment: This is much better. For some reason I thought that trying to select this way would break if I had multiple observations/points for each object lol. Guess I just need more practice to wrap my mind around how to do things properly in SQL.

Comment: It's a very different mindset...most coding languages are ultimately linear where you need this loop mentality.  SQL is set based, which requires a much different frame of mind.